# Mutating a dioxus UseState struct that doesn't implement clone

Tags: user-interface, rust, dioxus

I'm using Dioxus to build a UI. This UI relies heavily on a struct from a third-party library. This struct doesn't implement clone. The struct needs to be modified on button press. Consider this simplified example:

```rust
use dioxus::prelude::*;

struct ThirdPartyStruct(i64);

impl ThirdPartyStruct {
    fn add_one(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
    }
}

fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let third_party_struct = use_state(cx, || ThirdPartyStruct(0));

    cx.render(rsx! {
        button {
            onclick: move |_| third_party_struct.make_mut().add_one(),
            "Click me!"
        }
        p {
            "{third_party_struct.get().0}"
        }
    })
}
```

This does not compile, since `make_mut` requires clone to be implemented for `ThirdPartyStruct`. The real `ThirdPartyStruct` isn't nearly as simple and the real equivalent of `add_one` has to be used (so solutions like "use `+ 1` instead" are invalid). Implementing clone by hand would also be infeasible.

I have tried many things, including most of the methods for the `UseState` struct meant for modifying the contained struct. All of them either require the struct to be modified by value (like calling `+ 1` instead of `+= 1`) or need to have clone implemented.

Comment: What is the third party library you are trying to use this with?

Comment: @BeaBoxler the Sytem struct from the [sysinfo](https://lib.rs/crates/sysinfo) crate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of resolving this is wrapping the struct in a `RefCell`. It might not be the most memory safe way, but it *works*.

The side effect of this is the state does not know it has changed, so you will need to manually mark the component as dirty each time you call a mutating function with `cx.needs_update()`.

```rust
fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let third_party_struct = use_state(cx, || RefCell::new(ThirdPartyStruct(0)));

    cx.render(rsx! {
        button {
            onclick: move |_| {
                third_party_struct.borrow_mut().add_one();
                cx.needs_update();
            },
            "Click me!"
        }
        p {
            "{third_party_struct.get().borrow().0}"
        }
    })
}
```

It's worth noting I have not tried this with the sysinfo crate, but it works with your MRE.

Answer (score 1):

Dioxus has a separate hook called [use_ref](https://dioxuslabs.com/docs/0.3/guide/en/interactivity/hooks.html#use_ref-hook) for values that are not clone. It is possible to use interior mutability like RefCell inside of a use_ref hook, but it is not recommended because it can easily break updates

```rust
use dioxus::prelude::*;

struct ThirdPartyStruct(i64);

impl ThirdPartyStruct {
    fn add_one(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
    }
}

fn app(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let third_party_struct = use_ref(cx, || ThirdPartyStruct(0));

    cx.render(rsx! {
        button {
            onclick: move |_| third_party_struct.write().add_one(),
            "Click me!"
        }
        p {
            "{third_party_struct.read().0}"
        }
    })
}
```